# How to find scatter plot point in the source data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I have points in an Excel 2016 scatter plot chart:

[image]

---

I've hovered my mouse over a specific position in the chart.

The points at that position are possible outliers, so I want to look them up in the source data.

Is there a way that I can navigate to those points/records in the source data? Or do I need to manually search for rows that have the combination of `5, 17` in the x & y columns?

Comment: You can add data labels, then format the labels to show column C. The problem is that labels will overlap and you'll see just one value until you move it. I think VBA can fix that (search for how to display overlapping data labels......). Another method, slightly cumbersome, is manually typing the age and asset you want to find in other cells. Then create another column in your data to flag YES if they match by using an IF(AND) formula. Then filter your data on YES. A third option, maybe, is using your data to calculate outliers as another column. Not sure what the math would look like.

Comment: Thanks. Good ideas. An additional note: Excel seems to limit the number of labels that can be displayed to 1000. In my case, I have more than 1000 points in my scatter plot, so not all points are being labelled, which is unfortunate. Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rApk.png